# final instance variable can be reassigned to some other value using const in dart

Tags: dart

Does anyone know why the below code works in dart. `final` keyword is used to define constant variables. But the below code works little different. If we are using `const` with a different value it's working fine without giving error.

```
void main() {
    ExampleFinal exampleFinal = new ExampleFinal();
}

class ExampleFinal() {
    final a = 5;
    ExampleFinal() {
        // The below statement will not create any error. 
        // But if you are remove const in below line it'll show a compile time error.
        const a = 6;
        print(a); // Prints 6
    }
}
```

Is it a bug or a feature in dart? There is nothing like mentioned in document also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const a = 6;
```

creates a new variable that shadows the `final a = 5;`

This is possible because `{...}` creates a new scope in the constructor body.

If you add at the end of the constructor

```
print(this.a);
```

it will print `5`

Comment: Looks interesting. But it may confuse also. And there is no such thing is mentioned in the document also!

Comment: Haven't checked the docs for a while. A type and/or `var`, `const`, `final` before a variable always create a new one. In the same scope you get an error if there are name conflicts. Most languages I worked with behave very similar.